# Unable to identify deadlock

Tags: concurrency, rust

Most minimal example I could make ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=76c280d06791b537998620f3cca2db7a)):

```
use crossbeam::queue::SegQueue;
use parking_lot::{Mutex, MutexGuard};
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

struct ReadySignal {
    client: Arc<Mutex<Client>>,
    section: usize,
}

struct Client {
    id: usize,
    file: Vec<usize>,
}

fn main() {
    let max_clients = 10;
    let file_size = 1000;
    let req_q = Arc::new(SegQueue::new());
    let v: Vec<Arc<Mutex<Client>>> = Vec::new();
    let client_arr = Arc::new(Mutex::new(v));
    let client_arr_c = Arc::clone(&client_arr);
    thread::spawn(move || loop {
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10));
        let mut display = String::new();
        let client_arr_c = client_arr_c.lock();
        for i in client_arr_c.iter() {
            let client = i.lock();
            let total = client.file.len();
            let mut done = 0;
            for j in client.file.iter() {
                if *j == 1 {
                    done += 1;
                }
            }
            let percentage = (done as f64 / total as f64) * 100.0;
            let client_per: String = format!("Client {}: {:.2}%\n", client.id, percentage);
            MutexGuard::unlock_fair(client);
            display += &client_per;
        }
        MutexGuard::unlock_fair(client_arr_c);
        println!("\x1B[2J\x1B[1;1H{}", display);
    });
    let client_arr_c = Arc::clone(&client_arr);
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        for i in 0..max_clients {
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
            let mut file_init = 0;
            if i == 0 {
                file_init = 1;
            }
            let client = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Client {
                id: i + 1,
                file: vec![file_init; file_size],
            }));
            let clientc = Arc::clone(&client);
            let req_qc = Arc::clone(&req_q);
            thread::spawn(move || {
                for j in 0..file_size {
                    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10));
                    let clientcc = clientc.lock();
                    if clientcc.file[j] == 0 {
                        let req = ReadySignal {
                            client: Arc::clone(&clientc),
                            section: j,
                        };
                        req_qc.push(req);
                        MutexGuard::unlock_fair(clientcc);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            });
            let clientc = Arc::clone(&client);
            let req_qc = Arc::clone(&req_q);
            thread::spawn(move || loop {
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(20));
                let clientc = clientc.lock();
                if req_qc.is_empty() {
                    continue;
                }
                let req = req_qc.pop().unwrap();
                if clientc.file[req.section] == 1 {
                    let mut req_client = req.client.lock();
                    req_client.file[req.section] = 1;
                    MutexGuard::unlock_fair(req_client);
                    MutexGuard::unlock_fair(clientc);
                } else {
                    req_qc.push(req);
                }
            });
            let clientc = Arc::clone(&client);
            client_arr_c.lock().push(clientc);
        }
    });
    loop {}
}
```

Dependencies are `crossbeam = "0.7.3"` and `parking_lot = "0.11.0"`.
Better run it in a new Cargo project rather than the playground because the stdout formatting is messed up there.

The basic idea of this program is to simulate a simple p2p network. The first client already has the file (`client.file` has  a `Vec` filled with 1s). A new client joins every second with no file (`client.file` has  a `Vec` filled with 0s). Right after a new client is created, 2 threads are created for that client. The first thread (line 62-77) checks which parts of the client's file is 0 and puts a request in the queue for each. The second thread (line 80-97) takes requests out from the queue and changes those 0s into 1s.
The thread at the start (line 24-47) is for checking the progress and printing the output by looping over a vec containing all the clients, every 10ms.

If you run this you can see the percentages of each client keep increasing up to a point where it stops. This point varies from run to run. The intended behavior is for all clients to reach 100%. But this intended behavior has happened only  a very few times. What could be causing the deadlock? And how do I stop that?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [mre]. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here.

Comment: @JohnKugelman updated with MRE.

Comment: I do see something that is most likely a mistake: on line 79 of the playground, you call `thread::sleep` while the mutex is locked -- which means this thread is hogging the mutex while it twiddles its thumbs. You can't get work done in parallel that way because all access to a mutex has to be sequential. In fact it looks like pretty much all your work is done with a mutex locked, which is probably why you're using `MutexGuard::unlock_fair` to influence the thread scheduling -- that's not usually what you want because it means there's some implicit dependency between threads that should be...

Comment: ... made explicit (perhaps by sending signals between threads, joining threads, or simply using fewer threads in the first place).

Comment: @trentcl I just redid the whole thing with more details.

Comment: This question has been [cross-posted to users.rust-lang.org](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/unable-to-identify-why-this-deadlock-is-happening/49077) and I added a post there to partially explain what I think is happening. Not enough to make an answer though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, the main source of deadlocks is locking two primitives at the same time. For example:

```
Thread 1:
 lock A
 lock B
 ...
 unlock B
 unlock A

Thread 2:
 lock B
 lock A
 ...
 unlock A
 unlock B
```

If both threads start more-or-less at the same time, thread 1 may lock A and thread 2 may lock B, and then... deadlock!

If you cannot avoid locking both objects, the obvious workaround is to always lock them in the same order: first A, then B. The unlock order is not as important.

In your code, there are two places where you have more than one object locked at the same time:

1. The main thread always locks the array first and then every client inside in order. This cannot cause a deadlock because the only other place where array is locked is in the last line `client_arr_c.lock().push(clientc)` and no other locks are held there.
2. The thread that dequeues requests locks the current client AND the requester client. Here lies the problem!

Rewriting that code reveals another issue: there is a race between `is_empty()` and `pop().unwrap()`. In between these two, another thread may enter and empty the queue. When you do the `pop().unwrap()` you will panic (note that the client lock does not protect the queue).

The race popping the queue is easy to fix:

```
let req = match req_qc.pop() {
    Err(_) => continue,
    Ok(x) => x,
};
```

About the locking of both clients, since you know what file the request wants, you could lock the current client, copy the file, unlock the client, then lock the requester, paste the file and unlock the requester. The locks don't overlap, no problem.

I guess that your real code does more than setting a 1, so that may not be feasible or optimal. If you really need both clients locked at the same time. you can for example compare the client ids and always lock the lower id first and the greater id last. Since the `id` is a `usize` that is `Copy` you can keep a copy outside of the clients: the id that owns the thread may be a local variable, and that of the requester may be in an extra field in the signal struct.

```
struct ReadySignal {
    client_id: usize, //same as client.id, but unlocked
    client:  Arc<Mutex<Client>>,
    section: usize,
}
```

Now when you want to lock both clients, you do:

```
let (clientc, mut req_client) = match client_id.cmp(&req.client_id) {
    std::cmp::Ordering::Less => {
        let a = clientc.lock();
        let b =  req.client.lock();
        (a, b)
    }
    std::cmp::Ordering::Greater => {
        let b =  req.client.lock();
        let a = clientc.lock();
        (a, b)
    }
    std::cmp::Ordering::Equal => {
        req_qc.push(req);
        continue;
    }
};
```

Do not forget what to do if the client is the same. Your original code sidestepped the issue by checking that the requested piece must is available before locking the second one, but here I have to lock both at the same time, so I cannot check that. Instead, if both clients are the same just repush and repeat.

There is a bit of rework here and there to make the borrow checker happy, and there are some clear pending optimizations, but this code seems to work fine ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=948a27b1feb36161c8a396e46ec5849a)).

```
use std::thread;
use std::time::{Duration};
use std::sync::Arc;
use crossbeam::queue::SegQueue;
use parking_lot::{Mutex, MutexGuard};

struct ReadySignal {
    client_id: usize,
    client:  Arc<Mutex<Client>>,
    section: usize,
}

struct Client {
    id:      usize,
    file:    Vec<usize>,
}

fn main() {
    let max_clients = 10;
    let file_size = 1000;
    let req_q = Arc::new(SegQueue::new());
    let v: Vec<Arc<Mutex<Client>>> = Vec::new();
    let client_arr = Arc::new(Mutex::new(v));
    let client_arr_c = Arc::clone(&client_arr);
    thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10));
            let mut display = String::new();
            let client_arr_c = client_arr_c.lock();
            for (_ii, i) in client_arr_c.iter().enumerate() {

                let client = i.lock();
                let total = client.file.len();
                let mut done = 0;
                for j in client.file.iter() {
                    if *j == 1 {
                        done += 1;
                    }
                }
                let percentage = (done as f64/total as f64) * 100.0;
                let client_per: String = format!("Client {}: {:.2}%\n", client.id, percentage);
                MutexGuard::unlock_fair(client);
                display += &client_per;
            }
            MutexGuard::unlock_fair(client_arr_c);
            println!("\x1B[2J\x1B[1;1H{}",display);
            
        }
    });
    let client_arr_c = Arc::clone(&client_arr);
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        for i in 0..max_clients {
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
            let mut file_init = 0;
            if i == 0 {
                file_init = 1;
            }
            let client_id = i + 1;
            let client = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Client{
                id: client_id,
                file: vec![file_init;file_size],
            }));
            let clientc = Arc::clone(&client);
            let req_qc = Arc::clone(&req_q);
            thread::spawn(move || {
                for j in 0..file_size {
                    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10));
                    let clientcc = clientc.lock();
                    if clientcc.file[j] == 0 {
                        let req = ReadySignal{
                            client_id,
                            client: Arc::clone(&clientc),
                            section: j,
                        };
                        MutexGuard::unlock_fair(clientcc);
                        req_qc.push(req);
                        continue;
                    }
                    
                }
            });
            let clientc = Arc::clone(&client);
            let req_qc = Arc::clone(&req_q);
            thread::spawn(move || {
                loop {
                    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(20));
                    let req = match req_qc.pop() {
                        Err(_) => continue,
                        Ok(x) => x,
                    };
                    let (clientc, mut req_client) = match client_id.cmp(&req.client_id) {
                        std::cmp::Ordering::Less => {
                            let a = clientc.lock();
                            let b =  req.client.lock();
                            (a, b)
                        }
                        std::cmp::Ordering::Greater => {
                            let b =  req.client.lock();
                            let a = clientc.lock();
                            (a, b)
                        }
                        std::cmp::Ordering::Equal => {
                            req_qc.push(req);
                            continue;
                        }
                    };
                    if clientc.file[req.section] == 1 {
                        req_client.file[req.section] = 1;
                        MutexGuard::unlock_fair(req_client);
                        MutexGuard::unlock_fair(clientc);
                    } else {
                        MutexGuard::unlock_fair(req_client);
                        MutexGuard::unlock_fair(clientc);
                        req_qc.push(req);
                    }
                }
            });
            let clientc = Arc::clone(&client);
            client_arr_c.lock().push(clientc);
        }
    });
    loop {
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
    }
}
```

Also, I've added a sleep in the empty loop at the end of the main thread to stop it from eating 100% of one CPU core.